# Javascript: On OnChange event passing array variable to another function

Tags: javascript

In one JavaScript function, I am declaring an array variable `arr1`, and when user changes a dropdown value, `arr1` is passed to another function named `nat()`, which appends the value to that array.

If the user selects another item from drop down, it should call this same function `nat()` and append that value to the same array.
So `arr1[0] = 2` and `arr1[1] = 2`

Currently the problem is this: when I pass an array variable while selecting the dropdown, it's sending the array as a string to function `nat()`. I've tried all the different combinations.

```
function function1(){

var table = document.getElementById("device1");
new arr1=new Array();

var row1 = table.insertRow(1);
var cell1= row1.innerHTML = "<select name='owner' id='ownerval' 
                             onChange=nat('"+arr1+"')><option 
                             value='group'>Select Group</option><option 
                             value='FG'>FG</option><option 
                             value='PG'>PG</option><option
                             value='SG'>SG</option></select>";
}
function nat(arr1){
arr1[arr1.length]=2;
alert ("Value: "+ arr1[0]); 
}
```

In alert `arr1[0]` is coming as "Undefined".

Comment: Arrays have a `push` method, that will append an item to the end of an array. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: You cannot have string literals spanning multiple lines in javascript

Comment: Consider using JavaScript (namely, [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)) to attach event listeners rather than HTML.

Comment: @Musa you could escape the new line. Not saying it is the best way to generate HTML by any means, but it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
new arr1=new Array();

function function1(){

var table = document.getElementById("device1");

var row1 = table.insertRow(1);
var cell1= row1.innerHTML = "<select name='owner' id='ownerval' 
                         onChange=nat(arr1)><option 
                         value='group'>Select Group</option><option 
                         value='FG'>FG</option><option 
                         value='PG'>PG</option><option
                         value='SG'>SG</option></select>";
}
function nat(arr1o){
arr1o.push(2);
alert ("Value: "+ arr1o[0]); 
}
```

Comment: Should use `push` method to append to an array.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer lem2802!

But i am getting error ReferenceError: arr1 is not defined after following above solution.

Comment: Anyone have any suggestions??